# Переопределение функций свойств get/set

Tags: c#, property

Задача: слияние узлов XML и классов, где свойства помеченные атрибутом ToXmlAttribute, являются атрибутами Xml (Node Name=""):

```
[ToXml]
public string Name {
   get{GetPropety("Name");} 
   set{SetPropety("Name", value);} 
}
```

для вычитки значений используется функция GetPropety("Name"), а для внесения изменений SetPropety("Name", value). Можно ли переопределить функции get и set, так чтобы каждый раз не вызывать Get/SetProperty? Возможно ли это реализовать через события?

Comment: А в чем проблема с вызовом этих функций?

Comment: Хотелось бы сократить  до public string Name {get; set;}, при большом количестве объектов, накладно прописывать функции

Comment: Вы можете сделать сниппет для быстрого ввода, если интересно - могу оформить ответом

Comment: создать сниппет не проблема, хотелось сократить код и трудозатраты

Comment: То есть проблема в том, что вам надо писать кучу классов? А это нельзя автоматизировать? Или сгенерировать классы на лету? Судя по описанию вашего вопроса, вам может помочь AOP (например [postsharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception)) для перехвата вызова геттеров\сеттеров, но мне кажется, проблема где то глубже

Comment: Если проблема в написании кода, сделайте себе простейший кодогенератор.

Comment: Здесь каждый класс узел иерархической системы XML, где есть свойства: одни связанные с Xml (атрибуты), другие - нет. Но выглядели бы они одинаково, с той лишь разницей, что некоторые помечены атрибутом ToXml.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете завести [индексатор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

```
class SampleCollection
{
   private Dictionary<string,string> props = new Dictionary<string,string>();

   public string this[string propName]
   {
      get { return prop[propName]; }
      set { prop[propName] = value; }
   }
}
```